# Por que meu código servidor não está funcionado com IPv6?

Tags: c, socket

Recentemente andei escrevendo um pequeno servidor em C usando a API de sockets do *UNIX* apenas para alguns testes. O programa funciona perfeitamente com *IPv4*, porém o mesmo não acontece com *IPv6*...

Segue o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#define STR_PORT "9009"

int make_server_socket(void){

    int sockfd;
    struct addrinfo *res=NULL, hints;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));

    hints.ai_flags=AI_PASSIVE;
    hints.ai_family=AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype=SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol=IPPROTO_TCP;

    if(getaddrinfo(NULL, STR_PORT, &hints, &res)!=0){

        sockfd=-1;

    }else{

        if((sockfd=socket(res->ai_family, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP))!=-1){

            if(bind(sockfd, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen)<0){

                sockfd=-1;
            }
        }

        freeaddrinfo(res);
    }

    return sockfd;
}

int main(void){

    int sockfd=make_server_socket();

    if(sockfd<0){

        printf("\n*make_server_socket(): ERROR!\n");

    }else{

        if(listen(sockfd, 1)<0){

            printf("\n*listen(): ERROR!\n");
            perror("ERROR DESCRIPTION");

        }else{

            int csockfd=accept(sockfd, NULL, NULL);

            if(csockfd<0){

                printf("\n*accept(): ERROR!\n");
                perror("ERROR DESCRIPTION");

            }else{

                int rv=write(csockfd, "Real Muthaphuckkin G's", 23);

                if(rv!=23){

                    printf("\nsend(23): FAIL\n");

                }else{

                    printf("\nsend(23): SUCCESSFUL\n");
                }

                close(csockfd);
            }

            close(sockfd);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Código compilado e em funcionamento:**

Conectando-se ao servidor via endereço local *IPv4*:

```
zherkezhi@zherkezhi :~/Documents/C$ nc -4 127.0.0.1 9009
Real Muthaphuckkin G's
zherkezhi@zherkezhi:~/Documents/C$ #Funcionou perfeitamente!
```

Conectando-se ao servidor via endereço local *IPv6*:

```
zherkezhi@zherkezhi:~/Documents/C$ nc -6 ::1 9009
zherkezhi@zherkezhi:~/Documents/C$ #não aconteceu nada *_*
```

**Saída do nmap (enquanto o servidor estava em execução):**

Escaneando endereço local *IPv4*:

```
zherkezhi@zherkezhi:~/Documents/C$ nmap 127.0.0.1

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-10-26 10:49 -03
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000052s latency).
Not shown: 997 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
631/tcp  open  ipp
3306/tcp open  mysql
9009/tcp open  pichat

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.06 seconds
```

Escaneando endereço local *IPv6*:

```
zherkezhi@zherkezhi:~/Documents/C$ nmap -6 ::1

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-10-26 10:46 -03
Nmap scan report for ip6-localhost (::1)
Host is up (0.000060s latency).
Not shown: 999 closed ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
631/tcp open  ipp

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.09 seconds
```

O que eu tenho que fazer para meu código funcionar com IPv6 corretamente?

Answer (score 4):

Você não consegue usar IPv4 e IPv6 no mesmo socket.

No caso em questão, se você quer atender IPv6 então você precisa especificar a família

```
hints.ai_family = AF_INET6;
```

ou então especificar o ipv6

```
if (getaddrinfo("::", STR_PORT, &hints, &res) !=0) {
```

para sua aplicação aceitar conexões IPv6, mas neste caso a aplicação não vai aceitar conexões IPv4.

## CORREÇÂO

É possível aceitar conexões IPv4 e IPv6 no mesmo socket através do uso de endereços especiais IPv6 chamados "IPv4-Mapped IPv6 Address". Neste caso, para fazermos bind em localhost usamos o endereço IPv6 ::0.0.0.0.

Abaixo vai um exemplo de uso.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#include <errno.h>

static char port[10] = "9009";
static char addr[20] = "::0.0.0.0";

static int make_server_socket(void)
{
  int sockfd;
  struct addrinfo *res = NULL, hints;

  memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));

  hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
  hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
  hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
  hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

  if (getaddrinfo(addr, port, &hints, &res) !=0)
  {
    printf("* erro em getaddrinfo\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  if ((sockfd=socket(res->ai_family, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) == -1)
  {
    int err = errno;
    printf("* erro %d na criacao do socket\n", err);
    exit(1);
  }

  int reuse = 1;
  if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const char*)&reuse, sizeof(reuse)) < 0)
  {
    int err = errno;
    printf("* erro %d no setsockopt\n", err);
    exit(1);
  }

  if (bind(sockfd, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen) < 0)
  {
    int err = errno;
    printf("* erro %d no bind\n", err);
    exit(1);
  }

  freeaddrinfo(res);
  return sockfd;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int sockfd = make_server_socket();

  if (argc > 1)
    strncpy(addr, argv[1], 19);

  if (argc > 2)
    strncpy(port, argv[2], 9);

  if (listen(sockfd, 1) < 0)
  {
    int err = errno;
    printf("* erro %d no listen\n", err);
    exit(1);
  }

  for (;;)
  {
    int csockfd = accept(sockfd, NULL, NULL);
    if (csockfd == -1)
    {
      int err = errno;
      printf("* erro %d no accept\n", err);
      exit(1);
    }

    printf("* conexao iniciada\n");

    int rv = write(csockfd, "Real Muthaphuckkin G's\n", 24);
    if (rv == -1)
    {
      int err = errno;
      printf("* errno %d no envio\n");
      exit(1);
    }
    printf("* envio bem sucedido\n");
    close(csockfd);
    printf("* conexao fechada\n");
  }
}
```

Netstat no Linux:

```
zv@localhost Misc]$ netstat -ant | grep 9009  
tcp6       0      0 :::9009                 :::*                    OUÇA      
[zv@localhost Misc]$
```

Telnet no Linux:

```
[zv@localhost Misc]$ telnet -4 127.0.0.1 9009
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
Real Muthaphuckkin G's
Connection closed by foreign host.

[zv@localhost Misc]$ telnet -6 ::1 9009
Trying ::1...
Connected to ::1.
Escape character is '^]'.
Real Muthaphuckkin G's
Connection closed by foreign host.
[zv@localhost Misc]$
```